# Use CardView with Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-cardview

I'm trying to use the cardView in my app but it crashes everytime I open it. This is the error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.cardview.R$styleable" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.BlueMango.informazioni-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

I read in another questions that I need to import the cardView library from the sdk. I did it but nothing changed. Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Library Project you need to import in Eclipse (via Import->Existing Android Code into Workspace) is located in your Android SDK folder: ***Android\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\cardview***

Comment: I already solve it for myself but thanks for the answer and since you're right I'll mark your answer as correct.